# Web3: constant get function - error: is not a function

Tags: solidity

I keep getting this error where my web3 throws an error saying that getCardByID is not a function, but it is clearly defined in my deployed smart contract. What am I missing here?

Smart contract code:

```
function getCardById(uint id) constant returns (uint idRet, string name, string email, string comment){

for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    if (cards[i].id == id) {

        idRet = cards[i].id;

        name = cards[i].name;

        email = cards[i].email;

        comment = cards[i].comment;

        return;

        }

    }
```

HTML/Jscript code:

```
 //pulls a record from the blockchain based on ID #
      function getCardByID() {
          web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0], 'scrubbed');
          var vID = $("#id").val(); //pulls value from user input field
          var card = contract_instance.getCardByID(vID);
          console.log(card);
      }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated; thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCardByID` is not a function, but `getCardById` is.

Note the lower-case `d` in the function definition of the contract.

Comment: Thank you for catching that... clearly it's been a long day - yikes